# How to make this live validation work with my sql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

my intention is to make a live validation , which i found a side that tutorial but they are using old sql , i wanted to use my sql PDO , but i cant make it work , even my database having the same name , it still say ok.

how do i make it work , before you check my code , please look and download the link to check it out, thank.

download from here:
[Please Check This Link](http://papermashup.com/jquery-php-mysql-username-availability-checker/)

my code(i changed some to PDO but still wont work)
dbConnector.php

```
<?php

    class DbConnector {

    var $link;

    function DbConnector(){
            try{
                $this->link = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=system', 'root', '123456');
                $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die("this is not connected");
            }

        }

      //*** Function: query, Purpose: Execute a database query ***
        function query($query) {
        try{
        $this->link->prepare($query);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die("fail to prepare");
        }
        return $this->link;
    }

    }

    ?>
```

check.php

```
<?php
include("dbConnector.php");
$connector = new DbConnector();

$username = trim(strtolower($_POST['username']));

$query = "SELECT air_users FROM USER_NAME WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
$result = $connector->query($query);
$result->execute(array($username));

$num = $result->rowCount();
$num = $result->fetch();

echo $num;
// mysql_close();
?>
```

i dont have any error , but still it wont work. thank for helping out.

Comment: Ok, you say you don't get any error, but what output do you see?

Comment: When you're using PDO, please use its advantages. Don't insert your php var in the query, use prepared statement. 
`$_POST` instead of `$POST` line5 also

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the returned value of `$this->link->prepare($query);` not the `$this->link` itself. To make it work, rewrite your query this way:

```
function query($query) {
  return $this->link->prepare($query);
}
```

Comment: still wont work , i keep getting acess even i have the name at database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the $username variable is been interpreted on the string, as you have it.

```
"SELECT users FROM USER_NAME WHERE username = :username' LIMIT 1";
...
execute(array(':username' => $username));
```

and on the query method call prepeare like:

```
  $this->link->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
```

or

```
 "SELECT users FROM USER_NAME WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    ...
 execute(array($username));
```

And the prepare method should be call like you have it on your example:

```
$this->link->prepare($query);
```

And on the query method you return the $query or the string. You should return the instance or execute in the query method.

```
function query($query) {
    try{
    $this->link->prepare($query);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die("fail to prepare");
    }
    return $this->link;
}
```

[See](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: yep, my bad i will update the example. The array in the execute method should contain a colom at the begining to macht

Comment: do you make it work? why i still access even i have the name on the database ? i am using the 2nd method. thank for helping friend.